# How do I run XWiki in Centos7 with 1GB RAM?

Tags: linux, centos, java, tomcat

According to the XWiki docs, 1GB should be sufficient to run XWiki.

https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Performances/#HMemory

> For Java 8 (i.e. XWiki >= 8.1). Notice that there's no permgen anymore in Java 8:
>   Small and medium installs: A minimum of 1024MB (-Xmx1024m)

I installed and configured Tomcat according to the documentation.

https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Installation/InstallationWAR/InstallationTomcat/

I have (in `conf/tomcat.conf`)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=125m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

And sometimes

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

And it is crashing randomly. I cannot even add another user. This is the first part of the dump file `hs_err_pid11420.log`

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 105709568 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Unscaled Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 4GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 4GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2766), pid=11420, tid=0x00007fcd0d720700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
```

I am not using HSQLDB. I am using Postgresql on the same server.

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core), XWiki 10.11.8

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a swapfile.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-centos-7

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=125 bs=1MiB # 125 MB
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
sysctl vm.swappiness=10
sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

I reduced Tomcat to 750MB (which seems crazy high for an empty wiki).

`conf/tomcat.conf`

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=125m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

Now my `top` shows pretty much nothing free but it doesn't crash.

```
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1015008 total,    67244 free,   844308 used,   103456 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   127996 total,        0 free,   127996 used.    18232 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
13409 tomcat    20   0 3065908 741928   3724 S  0.3 73.1   2:30.68 java
```